# Add text on certain lines of a file, with the added text depending on the output of a command that takes a substring from the line

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to make a shell script to take an input file (thousands of lines) and produce an output file that is the same except that on certain lines there will be added text.  When the text is added to the (middle of) the line, the exact added text will depend on a substring on the line.  The correlation between the substring and the added text is complex and comes from an external program that I can call in the shell.  I don't have the source for this converter program nor any control over how the mapping is done.

To explain further...

I have an input file of this general format:

```
Blah Blah Unimportant
Something Something
FIELD_INFO(field_name_1, output_1),
  FIELD_INFO(field_name_2, output_2),
Yadda Yadda
```

The whole file needs to be copied, with added text, but the only important parts for me are the field names (e.g. field_name_1, field_name_2).  I have a command line program called "converter" that can take a file of field names and output a list of corresponding actions.  Converter cannot operate directly on the input file.  The input to converter needs to be *just* field names and the output of converter has extra information I don't need:

```
converter_field_name_1 "action1" /* Use this action for field_name_1 */
converter_field_name_2 "action2" /* use this action for field_name_2 */
```

The desire is to create a second file that looks like this:

```
Blah Blah Unimportant
Something Something
FIELD_INFO(field_name_1, action1, output_1),
  FIELD_INFO(filed_name_2, action2, output_2),
Yadda Yadda
```

Here is the script I'm working on, but I've hit a wall (or two):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="input_file"

# Let's create an array of the field names to feed to the converter program
field_array=($(sed -e '/^\s*FIELD_INFO/ s/FIELD_INFO(\(.*\),.*),/\1/' -e 't' -e 'd' < ${filename}))

# Save the array to a file, to be able to use the converter's file option
printf "%s\n" "${field_array[@]}" > script_field_names.txt

# Use converter on the whole file and extract only the actions into another array
action_array=($(converter -f script_field_names.txt | cut -d'"' -f 2))

# I will make and use an associative array and try to use
# sed to do the substitution
declare -A mapper
for i in ${!field_array[*]}
do
mapper[${field_array[i]}]=${action_array[i]}
done

#Now go back through the file and add action names (source file unchanged)
sed -e "s/FIELD_INFO(\(.*\),\(.*?),\)/FIELD_INFO(\1, ${mapper[\1], \2}/" < ${filename}
```

I know now that I can't use the sed group capture "\1" as an index into the mapper array like this. It is not working as a key and the output looks like this:

```
Blah Blah Unimportant
Something Something
FIELD_INFO(field_name_1, ,  output_1),
  FIELD_INFO(field_name_2, ,  output_2),
Yadda Yadda
```

My actual script has debug statements scattered throughout and I know the field array, action array, and mapper array are all getting created correctly.  But my idea of using the group capture substring from sed as the index into the mapper array is not working because I now know that sed expands the variables *before* running in the sub-shell, so the mapper[] array is not seeing the substring as an index.

What should I be doing instead?  This script may only be used once, but it's too time consuming and error prone to do the addition of the action strings by hand.  I want to come up with a way to make this work but I can't tell if I'm close or completely on the wrong path.

Comment: please update the question with the **exact** output from `converter` for the 2 sample inputs (`field_name_1` / `field_name_2`) ... no comments, no extra characters/symbols; does it really output the string `convert_field_name_1` or `field_name_1`?  is `action1` wrapped in double quotes? can `action1` contain white space? do all lines of interest contain the literal string `FIELD_INFO` or is this a general term and in the real data file you have a variable list of strings to search for?

Comment: @markp-fuso The output of the converter is as shown, including the comments and the prepended "converter_".  Action is always wrapped in double quotes.  Action can contain most special characters but not white space, comma, back tick, at sign, dollar sign, single quote, or double quote.  All lines of interest contain FIELD_INFO and there are no lines that contain FIELD_INFO that are *not* of interest.  Thank you for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sed -e "s/FIELD_INFO(\(.*\),\(.*?),\)/FIELD_INFO(\1, ${mapper[\1], \2}/" < ${filename}`
> [...]
> I now know that sed expands the variables before running in the sub-shell, so the mapper[] array is not seeing the substring as an index.

Good job identifying the problem.  Also, the non-greedy quantifier `.*?` does not work with `sed` and `${mapper[\1], \2}` should probably be `${mapper[\1]}, \2`.

If you want to keep your current approach I see two options.

- Do the replacement line by line in bash, either by creating a giant sed command string that lists the action for each line, or by executing sed inside a loop for each line while creating the command strings on the fly.
- Instead of the array `mapper`, create a file that lists the actions to be inserted in the order from the file. Then use GNU sed's `R filename` command. This command inserts the next line from `filename`. You can use this to insert the correct action each time you come across a filed. However, the linebreak is inserted too. So you have to fiddle with the hold space and so on to remove these linebreaks afterwards.

Both options are not that great. Therefore I'd switch to `awk` to insert the actions:

```
sed -En 's/^\s*FIELD_INFO\(([^,]*).*/\1/p' "$filename" > fields
converter -f fields | cut -d\" -f2 > actions
awk '/^\s*FIELD_INFO\(/ {getline a < "actions"; sub(",", ", " a ",")} 1' "$filename"
```

With GNU grep you can simplify the first line to

```
grep -Po '^\s*FIELD_INFO\(\K[^,]*' "$filename" > fields
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, looking at both what I *could* do and what I *should* do. I'm marking yours as the accepted answer because I did, in fact, switch to using awk for the insert.  I thought awk was probably the right way but I was struggling with not understanding the syntax or knowing where to start.  A user had commented on my question within 5 minutes of my posting with an awk suggestion and i was able to learn from it before they deleted the comment.  My final script looks a bit like your suggestion except longer and less elegant. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try,

```
sed -n -e 's/^[ ]*FIELD_INFO(\(.*\),.*,/\1/p' -- input_file > script_field_names.txt
printf '/^[ ]*FIELD_INFO(%s,/ s/(\\(.[^,]*\\), \\(.[^)]*\\))/(\\1, %s, \\2)/\n' \
    $(converter -f script_field_names.txt | cut -d'"' -f 2 |
      paste -- script_field_names.txt -) |
    sed -f /dev/stdin -- input_file
```

where

- `paste` emits the map of fields (from file) and actions (from stdin)
- `printf` emits a script read by `sed` from stdin
- each script line becomes: `/^[ ]*FIELD_INFO(fieldnameN,/ s/(\(.[^,]*\), \(.[^)]*\))/(\1, actionN, \2)/`

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  If I had thought about the fact that I could produce custom commands for sed and send them to sed in the script via stdin, this is probably the way I would have done it.  I think it's pretty cool.  I did end up using awk for the insertion, which was good for me since I learned more about awk, but I also like your approach.